# How to place a plus symbol over top of a input field

Tags: html, css, button, input, tags

[The current output of my pgm(the red nd green circle were edited by me for ur understanding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WspQC.png)
The plus symbol inside red circle should be in the place of green circle.

Could you please help me with this..!!
Thanks in Advance,

MY CODE:

```css
 .plussymbol{
     font-size: 40px;
     color: #a4508b;
     background-color:transparent;
     border-radius: 20px;
     border: none;
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
    /*top: 37%;
     right: 28%;
    */
     padding-top: 15px;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
 .userip{
     width:90%;
     height: 65px;
     border-radius: 30px;
     font-size: 27px;
     font-weight: lighter;
     font-family: 'Hanalei Fill', cursive;
     background-color: #ece7e7;
     color: #000;
     border: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="userip" placeholder="Add Today's Task?" autocomplete="on">
        <button type="button" class="plussymbol">
                 <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
             </button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can do like this.

```
 .plussymbol{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #a4508b;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -60px;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it really worked but,Now the prblm is when i scroll down the plus symbol is moving down...Is there any way to fix it there permanantly

Comment: Yes,Using property ,"Position:sticky;" Helped me with that.Anyways thankyou for your help..!!